# chain-index does not connect

Tags: plutus, wallet, cardano-node, chain

I'm trying to run the cardano node, the cardano wallet and the chain index in three different docker images, but the chain index does not connect. The docker-compose file is below and the chain-index log is as follows:

```
chain-index_1     |
chain-index_1     | Command line config:
chain-index_1     | AppConfig {acLogConfigPath = Nothing, acMinLogLevel = Nothing, acConfigPath = Nothing, acCLIConfigOverrides = CLIConfigOverrides {ccSocketPath = Just "/ipc/node.socket", ccDbPath = Just "/chain-index.db", ccPort = Nothing, ccNetworkId = Just 1097911063}, acCommand = StartChainIndex}
chain-index_1     |
chain-index_1     | Logging config:
chain-index_1     | Representation {minSeverity = Info, rotation = Nothing, setupScribes = [ScribeDefinition {scKind = StdoutSK, scFormat = ScText, scName = "stdout", scPrivacy = ScPublic, scRotation = Nothing, scMinSev = Debug, scMaxSev = Emergency}], defaultScribes = [(StdoutSK,"stdout")], setupBackends = [KatipBK,AggregationBK,MonitoringBK,EKGViewBK], defaultBackends = [KatipBK,AggregationBK,EKGViewBK], hasEKG = Just (Endpoint ("localhost",12790)), hasGraylog = Nothing, hasPrometheus = Nothing, hasGUI = Nothing, traceForwardTo = Nothing, forwardDelay = Nothing, traceAcceptAt = Nothing, options = fromList []}
chain-index_1     |
chain-index_1     | Chain Index config:
chain-index_1     | Socket: /ipc/node.socket
chain-index_1     | Db: /chain-index.db
chain-index_1     | Port: 9083
chain-index_1     | Network Id: Testnet (NetworkMagic {unNetworkMagic = 1097911063})
chain-index_1     | Security Param: 2160
chain-index_1     | Store from: BlockNo 0
```

The docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  cardano-node:
    image: inputoutput/cardano-node #:1.33.0
    environment:
      NETWORK:
    volumes:
      - node-${NETWORK}-db:/data
      - node-ipc:/ipc
    restart: on-failure
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        compress: "true"
        max-file: "10"
        max-size: "50m"
    ports:
      - 3001:3001

  cardano-wallet:
    image: inputoutput/cardano-wallet:2022.1.18
    volumes:
      - wallet-${NETWORK}-db:/wallet-db
      - node-ipc:/ipc
    ports:
      - 8090:8090
    entrypoint: []
    command: bash -c "
        ([[ $$NETWORK == \"mainnet\" ]] && $$CMD --mainnet) ||
        ($$CMD --testnet /config/${NETWORK}/genesis-byron.json)
      "
    environment:
      CMD: "cardano-wallet serve --node-socket /ipc/node.socket --database /wallet-db --listen-address 0.0.0.0"
      NETWORK: testnet
    restart: on-failure
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        compress: "true"
        max-file: "10"
        max-size: "50m"

  chain-index:
    image: plutus-apps-dev
    volumes:
        - node-ipc:/ipc
        - chain-index.db:/mnt/chain-index.db
    ports:
        - 9083:9083
    entrypoint: []
    command: bash -c "cd /home/user/plutus-apps && ./dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.10.4.20210212/plutus-chain-index-0.1.0.0/x/plutus-chain-index/build/plutus-chain-index/plutus-chain-index  --socket-path /ipc/node.socket --db-path /tmp/chain-index.db --network-id 1097911063 start-index"
    restart: on-failure
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        compress: "true"
        max-file: "10"
        max-size: "50m"

volumes:
  chain-index.db:
  node-mainnet-db:
  node-testnet-db:
  node-alonzo-purple-db:
  wallet-mainnet-db:
  wallet-testnet-db:
  wallet-alonzo-purple-db:
  node-ipc:
  node-config:
```

Comment: NOTE: I'm doing it in a single docker image following: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/blob/main/plutus-pab/test-node/README.md which seems to work. Also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6AyZIZ0vaE&list=PLNEK_Ejlx3x2sBWXHdFBRgkzPF6N-1LVi&index=10